# Validation for 10 digit mobile number and Showing Color On Input If Invalid

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I need the red color to appear on the input field when input is not up to 10 digits and the color should turn green when digits are up to 10.

Please see my code below Thanks;

```js
function check()
{

    var mobile = document.getElementById('mobile');
   
    
    var message = document.getElementById('message');

   var goodColor = "#03b800";
    var badColor = "#f00a0a "; 
  
    if(mobile.value.length!=10){
       
        mobile.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
        message.style.color = goodColor;
        message.innerHTML = "required 10 digits, match requested format!"
        }
        else if(mobile.value.length <10){
       
        mobile.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
        message.style.color = badColor;
        message.innerHTML = "required 10 digits, match requested format!"
    }}
```

```html
<input name="mobile"  id="mobile" type="number" required onkeyup="check(); return false;" ><span id="message"></span>
```

Comment: The code you posted has a syntax error.

Comment: That's why I came for help.  I think the error is coming from <10 which I am trying to use as if length is lesser than 10.

Comment: The error *was* coming from `!=<10`, which is an error. It's fixed now. However, it still doesn't make sense: you turn the field green ("goodColor") when the length is **not** equal to 10.

Comment: I wouldn't post this issue if I knew what to do.

Comment: Well it's really hard to see the problem. `if(mobile.value.length!=10){` means, "If the length of the field value is not equal to 10".  Thus, when you type the first digit, that `if` will succeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic has an error.

```js
   if (mobile.value.length === 10){
       
        mobile.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
        message.style.color = goodColor;
        message.innerHTML = "Good job! You entered it correctly"
   }
   else {
        mobile.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
        message.style.color = badColor;
        message.innerHTML = "required 10 digits, match requested format!"
   }
```

Comment: Code without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste.
 Please edit your question and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

One other thing, we live in a mobile focused world now and onkeyup is not exactly friendly to most mobile browsers specs.

I would remove the attribute

`<input name="mobile"  id="mobile" type="number" required return false;" ><span id="message"></span>`

And bind to the on change event.

`$('#mobile').change(function(){ check(); });`

Comment: Please, how would I do that Nicholas?